# How can I open up PDFs in Google Drive with the Google Chrome PDF viewer?

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome, pdf

I'm in Google Chrome, but when I click on the PDF in Drive, I can only read it in the Drive viewer. I'd like to be able to read it in the normal Chrome viewer.

I know I can download the file and then open it up in the Chrome PDF viewer, but that seems like a workaround.

Is there any way to go straight from the file in Drive to the viewing it in the Chrome PDF viewer?

Comment: answer: click print, then cancel, and it will do exactly what you want. (I would add this as an answer, but this question is closed so cannot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible - [check out this thread on Google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/cCJF8su71_I).

It seems that the only choice is to connect an app to Google Drive for alternative PDF viewer (which is not the Chrome PDF viewer).

Comment: in [the linked answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95258/how-can-i-open-a-pdf-in-google-drive-in-the-same-way-as-a-downloaded-pdf?noredirect=1&lq=1), the first answer works fine: from the Drive pdf viewer, click print then cancel, and you will be in Chrome viewing the pdf

Answer (score -1):

You can right click the file,click "share" then you can get shareable link,just copy it.Open a new tab and go for the PDF by just pasting the link and click enter.

Comment: I just tested it and it still opens with the Drive PDF viewer. If that's indeed that case for you, could you share a working example of it? (GIF)

Comment: this answer doesn't work, but clicking the print button in Drive viewer then cancelling works perfectly.

Comment: @xdavidliu that should be an answer.

Comment: this question is closed, so nobody can add answers to it.